# Reading x lines of text at a time from a text file in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a method for a school project for displaying a list of contacts from a text file. Only four contacts are supposed to display at a time and then re-entering "d" should display the next 4 until all have been displayed. Does anyone have any advice in how I could achieve this? Right now I just have it so it reads all of the lines of text.

```
import java.util.Scanner;  import java.io.*; 
public class Contacts
{
  public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
  {
     File aFile = new File("contacts.txt");
     if (!aFile.exists())
       System.out.println("Cannot find file");
     else
     {
           Scanner in = new Scanner(aFile);
           String input;
           Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
           input = keyboard.nextLine();
           if (input.contains("d"))
           {
               String aLineFromFile;
               while(in.hasNext())
               {
                 aLineFromFile = in.nextLine();
                 System.out.println(aLineFromFile);
               }
               in.close();
           }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ad in a counter within in `while (in.hasNext())` loop, when it reaches `4`, use `keyboard.nextLine` to get the input from the user. Keep looping until you reach the end of the file or `input` is equal to `d`

Answer (score 0):

As MadProgrammer said, use a counter to track groups of 4.

```
else {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(aFile);
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();
    while(input.contains("d")) {
        int limit = 4;
        String aLineFromFile;
        while(in.hasNext() && limit > 0) {
            aLineFromFile = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(aLineFromFile);
            limit--;
        }

        if(in.hasNext()) {
            input = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```